# Octave packages unload themselves

Tags: import, package, octave, undefined-function

I'm using the Octave `io` package but it keeps unloading itself before I run the script. I'm using the `xlsread` function provided by `io` but I keep getting the following error:

```
warning: Functions for spreadsheet style I/O (.xls .xlsx .sxc .ods .dbf .wk1 etc.) are 
provided in the io package. See <http://octave.sf.net/io/>. 
Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can contribute missing 
functionality. 
error: 'xlsread' undefined near line 25 column 23
```

The package shows up when I type `pkg list` and there is an asterisk next to it when I type `pkg load io`. I even edited the `octaverc` to load `io` on startup. But I get that error when I run my script and when I check `pkg list` after my script fails the package is unloaded.

Comment: Do you have something like `clear all` at the beginning of your script? Assuming a certain command in your scripts clears the loaded packages, here's what you should try: in your script, import the package right before calling the function that uses it - and see if it helps.

Comment: Yeah that was it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I posted the above solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't invoke `clear all` (or similar commands) somewhere in your script, as this might also remove loaded libraries from memory.